# nginx to cdn or node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, cdn, rackspace-cloud

I have a simple example running ngnix that proxies to my node.js app running on localhost:3001. Now I want to add some optimizations and the problem is I'm not sure I completely understand the way ngnix config files work.

What I want to do is to serve index.html, about.html and main.js from the CDN via a proxy-forward through ngnix. I imagine I need to add something like a rewrite just for those two files (and an entire images and css directory eventually)

So user goes to mydomain.com .. ngnix kicks in and delivers index.html from cdn.mydomain.com/index.html.

Here is what I have now:

===================

```
proxy_redirect              off;                                                                                                                                                    
proxy_set_header            Host $host;                                                                                                                                             
proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                                                                                                                 
proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                                             

client_max_body_size        10m;                                                                                                                                                    
client_body_buffer_size     128k;                                                                                                                                                   
proxy_connect_timeout       600;                                                                                                                                                    
proxy_send_timeout          600;                                                                                                                                                    
proxy_read_timeout          600;                                                                                                                                                    
proxy_buffer_size           4k;                                                                                                                                                     
proxy_buffers               4 32k;                                                                                                                                                  
proxy_busy_buffers_size     64k;                                                                                                                                                    
proxy_temp_file_write_size  64k;                                                                                                                                                    
send_timeout                600;                                                                                                                                                    
proxy_buffering             off;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
####                                                                                                                                                                                
# the IP(s) on which your node server is running i choose the port 3001                                                                                                             
upstream app_yourdomian {                                                                                                                                                               
server 127.0.0.1:3001;                                                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
# the nginx server instance                                                                                                                                                         
server {                                                                                                                                                                                
listen 0.0.0.0:80;                                                                                                                                                                  
server_name ec2-75-101-203-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com ec2-75-101-203-200.compute-1.amazonaws;                                                                                      
access_log /var/log/nginx/yourdomain.log;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
# pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers and much more can be added, see nginx config options                                                              
location / {                                                                                                                                                                          
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                                                                                                                            
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                                                        
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;                                                                                                                                                   
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;                                                                                                                                                   
proxy_redirect off;                                                                                                                                                               

}


}
```

============================

Comment: Accessing a CDN through a reverse proxy completely defeats the purpose of using one....

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to proxy (not redirect to) index, about and main.js, then it would be something like having three more simple locations for each of the above

location = /index.html {
    proxy_pass ...
}

You might also want to take a look at http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

For locations without regex the most specific match is used.

Feel free to ask more in the mailing list http://mailman.nginx.org/mailman/listinfo/nginx